# Grabbing input values and select values to be put in an array and then displayed as a list

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take the input value of how much is spent, a value from a select options to explain what it was spent on and the list it on the bottom. My thought process was to put the values in an array and the display it towards the bottom, every time an input is submitted (I have multiple functions in one button) For example:

Today you spent:
15 Groceries
22 Going out
7 other: buying a pair of socks.

I have tried a few different methods:
I want to put a confirm in case user wants to add other ways money was spent. I've tried tweaking with .innerHTML and .value

```
function listSpending(){
  var repeat, spending= []; 
  while (repeat == true){spending.push(getElementById("money_spent").innerHTML,getElementById("whatOn").innerHTML )
    repeat = confirm("Did you spend money on anything else?");
    listTotalSpent.innerHTML= listOfSpending;`;
  }
}
```

This didn't work so I then attempted to try getElementByName. From what I read this is supposed to automatically grab the HTML with the same name and put it in an array. This wasn't displayed either.

```
function listSpending(){
  listOfSpending= document.getElementByName("moneySpent").value;
  listTotalSpent.innerHTML= listOfSpending;
}
```

HTML and JS:

```
 

   function storeCurrent(){
 currentCash= document.getElementById("current").value;
  // check if the entered value is number
  if (isNaN(Number(currentCash))) {
    alert("Numbers only");

  } else {
  currentTotal.innerHTML = `Current total is:${currentCash}`;
  }
   }

function checkOnWhat(val) {
  var element = document.getElementById('whatOn');
  if (val == 'Other')
    element.style.display = 'block';
  else
    element.style.display = 'none';
}


function deductFromTotal() {
  var spent = document.getElementById("money_spent").value;
  // check if the entered value is number
  if (isNaN(Number(spent))) {
    alert("Numbers only");

  } else {

    //currentCash = currentCash - spent;
    currentCash -= spent;
    currentTotal.innerHTML = `Current total is:${currentCash}`;
  }
}


/*function listSpending(){
  listOfSpending= document.getElementByName("moneySpent").value;
  listTotalSpent.innerHTML= listOfSpending;
}*/


/*function listSpending(){
    var repeat, spending= []; 
    while (repeat == true){spending.push(getElementById("money_spent").innerHTML,getElementById("whatOn").innerHTML )
      repeat = confirm("Did you spend money on anything else?");
  
      listTotalSpent.innerHTML= listOfSpending;`;
    }
    }*/
   <input type="amount" size=25 Placeholder="How much is in your wallet?" 
 id="current">
  <input type="button" value ="confirm" onClick="storeCurrent()">
         <br>
       <h2 id="currentTotal">Current total is:
        </h2>

    <input type="amount" size=25 Placeholder="How much did you spend today?" 
id="money_spent" name="moneySpent" required>
     <select name="moneySpent" onchange='checkOnWhat(this.value);' required>
           <option> Groceries
           <option>Going out
            <option>Bills
            <option>Other</select>
    <input type="text" name="whatOn" id="whatOn" style='display:none;' 
required />
    <p>
      <input type="button" value="confirm" onClick="deductFromTotal()" ; 
"listSpending()">

      <h3 name="totalSpent" id="totalSpent"> Today's Total Spending: </h3>
      <div id="listTotalSpent"></div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it so it is a [mcve] - you are for exampe missing `currentCash`

Comment: Thank you for the snippet! I have current cash towards the top of the HTML but didn't think it was necessary to include for this issue that I am having.

Comment: Please update the snippet to work

Comment: I have updated the snippets to include all necessary and needed information to understand the issue and resolve the problem

Comment: Still no currentCash

Comment: It's in the JS function called storeCurrent().

Comment: Run the snippet. Click the button. You get an error. You only have the currentCash define in one of the functions

Comment: I don't have an error with current cash or deduction. What I am trying to accomplish is grabbing the value that was inputted for the amount of money_spent and the select option of what on ex. groceries and have it listed on the bottom.

Comment: I ran the snippet and there is no error.

Comment: Run and click confirm. You are not testing your code, only testing it the way you know it will work :)

Comment: I have purposely commented out the functions where I attempted to solve this issue but am having issues which is why I'm looking for guidance and some advice from someone with more experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this

I had to change name to ID and set up an object

```js
var currentCash, items = {}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  currentCash = document.getElementById("current").value || 0;
  document.getElementById('whatOn').addEventListener("blur",function() {
    var sel = document.getElementById("moneySpent");
    var opt = new Option(this.value,this.value)
    sel.insertBefore(opt,sel.options[sel.options.length-1])
    sel.value=this.value;
    this.style.display="none"
    listSpending()
  })
});

function storeCurrent() {
  currentCash = document.getElementById("current").value;
  // check if the entered value is number
  if (isNaN(Number(currentCash))) {
    alert("Numbers only");
  } else {
    currentTotal.innerHTML = `Current total is:${currentCash}`;
  }
}

function checkOnWhat(val) {
  var element = document.getElementById('whatOn');
  element.style.display = val == 'Other' ? 'block':'none';
}


function deductFromTotal() {
  var spent = document.getElementById("spent").value;
  // check if the entered value is number
  if (isNaN(Number(spent))) {
    alert("Numbers only");
  } else {
    //currentCash = currentCash - spent;
    currentCash -= spent;
    currentTotal.innerHTML = `Current total is:${currentCash}`;
  }
  listSpending()
}

function listSpending() {
  var item = document.getElementById("moneySpent").value
  var spent = document.getElementById("spent").value;  
  if (items[item]) items[item]+= +spent;
  else items[item]= +spent;
  var list = document.getElementById("listTotalSpent");
  list.innerHTML ="";
  var total = 0;
  for (var item in items) {
    list.innerHTML += "<br/>"+item+":"+items[item];
    total += +items[item];
  }   
  document.getElementById("totalSpent").textContent = "Total $"+total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
<input type="amount" size=25 Placeholder="How much is in your wallet?" id="current">
<input type="button" value="confirm" onClick="storeCurrent()">
<br>
<h2 id="currentTotal">Current total is:
</h2>

<input type="amount" size=25 Placeholder="How much did you spend today?" id="spent" required>
<select id="moneySpent" onchange='checkOnWhat(this.value);' required>
  <option> Groceries</option>
  <option>Going out</option>
  <option>Bills</option>
  <option>Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="whatOn" id="whatOn" style='display:none;' required />
<p>
  <input type="button" value="confirm" onClick="deductFromTotal()">

  <h3> Today's Total Spending: </h3>
  <div id="listTotalSpent"></div>
  <div id="totalSpent"></div>
```

Comment: Updated to add the text entered into the sropdown

Comment: I ended up using a datalist so whatever gets typed in will show up on the bottom list as well, thanks for your help! There's a wealth of knowledge here so I'll be spending a few days going over this and will definitely reference this in the future!

Comment: @Victor Updated to total your spent values

Comment: Wow, thanks! There's so much to learn, I've only just started to get my feet wet but bit by bit I hope to one day be able to help people like you are helping me. After I go through your code and try to understand the different parts the next step is keeping track of the days, never ends but thus is the journey of coding :D